# dbt & Jinja: How can I keep the raw string when setting a variable?

Tags: jinja2, dbt

How can I keep the raw text when setting a variable within a macro in dbt?

I have tried `|e` but when I log to check, it doesn't seem to work.

My macro code:

```
{% macro process(column_name) %}
    {% set my_dict = {"\\T"|e:" ","\\\\T"|e:" "} %}
    {% for key, value in my_dict.items() %}
            {{ log(key, True) }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ return('') }}
{% endmacro %}
```

The log output is '\T' and '\\T' and I'm expecting '\\T' and '\\\\T'. I'm looking for something similar to `r''` when setting the variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Python, raw string *literals* impact how the interpreter parses the characters you wrap in quotes. Once it's in memory, there is no difference between a string that began its life as a raw string literal and one that began as an ordinary string literal. Try this in a Python interpreter:

```py
>>> raw = r"\T"
>>> print(raw)
\T
>>> raw
'\\T'
>>> ordinary = "\\T"
>>> print(ordinary)
\T
>>> ordinary
'\\T'
```

As you probably found out, jinja doesn't parse raw string literals. It does have a `{% raw %}` tag, but that is for escaping jinja syntax. The `escape` (or `e`) filter is for HTML escapes (so it'll replace spaces with `%20`, for example) and doesn't impact Python string literal parsing.

Using a `{% set %}` block will do what you want, and will not escape the backslashes:

```sql
{% macro raw_string() %}
{% set key -%}
\\T
{%- endset %}
{{ log(key, True) }}
{% endmacro %}
-- dbt run-operation raw_string
-- \\T
```

But that's going to be tedious if you have a lot of keys to deal with (You'll want a `set` block for each key, and then you'll have to define the dict separately, using the variables you defined in each set block).

Ultimately, this is a data entry challenge for you. Through that lens, you may just want to create a string that is valid JSON or YAML; recent version of dbt include `fromjson` and `fromyaml` methods in the jinja context. Thankfully, YAML is fine with backslashes in dictionary keys, and doesn't do any escaping:

```sql
{% macro process() %}

{% set data -%}
\\T: val
\\\\T: val
{%- endset %}

{% set my_dict = fromyaml(data) %}

{% for key, value in my_dict.items() %}
    {{ log(key, True) }}
{% endfor %}

{% endmacro %}
-- dbt run-operation process
-- \\T
-- \\\\T
```